# How can I use JavaFX to play video on 3D shape?

Tags: video, 3d, javafx, javafx-3d

I am new to JavaFX and Java. I am wondering how to make a scene on a surface of a cube or any polyhedra? I would like to play video back on the surface of any 3D shape. How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a sample which uses the in-built JavaFX MediaPlayer and takes periodic snapshots of a view on the media into a texture image mapped on to a 3D shape (in this case a Box).  A rotation animation around the Y Axis is added so that the sides of the box may be seen in perspective.

[image: 3D video]

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.media.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

// Display a rotating 3D box with a video projected onto its surface.
public class ThreeDMedia extends Application {

    private static final String MEDIA_URL =
            "http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv";

    private static final int SCENE_W = 640;
    private static final int SCENE_H = 400;

    private static final double MEDIA_W = 540 * 2/3;
    private static final double MEDIA_H = 209 * 2/3;

    private static final Color INDIA_INK = Color.rgb(35, 39, 50);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // create a 3D box shape on which to project the video.
        Box box = new Box(MEDIA_W, MEDIA_H, MEDIA_W);
        box.setTranslateX(SCENE_W / 2);
        box.setTranslateY(SCENE_H / 2);

        // create a media player for the video which loops the video forever.
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(new Media(MEDIA_URL));
        player.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);

        // create a media view for the video, sized to our specifications.
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(player);
        mediaView.setPreserveRatio(false);
        mediaView.setFitWidth(MEDIA_W);
        mediaView.setFitHeight(MEDIA_H);

        // project the video on to the 3D box.
        showMediaOnShape3D(box, mediaView);

        // rotate the box.
        rotateAroundYAxis(box);

        // create a point light source a fair way away so lighting is reasonably even.
        PointLight pointLight = new PointLight(
                Color.WHITE
        );
        pointLight.setTranslateX(SCENE_W / 2);
        pointLight.setTranslateY(SCENE_H / 2);
        pointLight.setTranslateZ(-SCENE_W * 5);

        // add a bit of ambient light to make the lighting more natural.
        AmbientLight ambientLight = new AmbientLight(
                Color.rgb(15, 15, 15)
        );

        // place the shape and associated lights in a group.
        Group group = new Group(
                box,
                pointLight,
                ambientLight
        );

        // create a 3D scene with a default perspective camera.
        Scene scene = new Scene(
                group,
                SCENE_W, SCENE_H, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED
        );
        scene.setFill(INDIA_INK);
        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
        scene.setCamera(camera);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);

        // start playing the media, showing the scene once the media is ready to play.
        player.setOnReady(stage::show);
        player.setOnError(Platform::exit);
        player.play();
    }

       // Project video on to 3D shape.
    private void showMediaOnShape3D(Shape3D shape3D, final MediaView mediaView) {
        PhongMaterial material = new PhongMaterial();
        shape3D.setMaterial(material);

        Scene mediaScene = new Scene(
                new Group(mediaView),
                MEDIA_W, MEDIA_H
        );
        SnapshotParameters snapshotParameters = new SnapshotParameters();
        snapshotParameters.setViewport(
                new Rectangle2D(
                        0, 0, MEDIA_W, MEDIA_H
                )
        );
        WritableImage textureImage = mediaView.snapshot(
                snapshotParameters,
                null
        );
        material.setDiffuseMap(textureImage);

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                mediaView.snapshot(
                        snapshotParameters,
                        textureImage
                );
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    // Rotates a shape around the y axis indefinitely.
    private void rotateAroundYAxis(Shape3D shape3D) {
        RotateTransition rotateY = new RotateTransition(
                Duration.seconds(10),
                shape3D
        );

        rotateY.setAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
        rotateY.setFromAngle(360);
        rotateY.setToAngle(0);
        rotateY.setCycleCount(RotateTransition.INDEFINITE);
        rotateY.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);

        rotateY.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very awesome to see that it also works when you apply it on a Sphere or a Cylinder. Thanks for sharing that!

Answer (score 9):

Actually, you can play video on any 3D shape.

There's an excelent project for video playing from [@caprica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2625478/caprica) called [VLCJ](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj): A Java framework for the [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) media player.

While the project is intended for rendering in AWT canvas, the author has done some [tests](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-javafx) to render it also in JavaFX `Canvas`.

Based on his JavaFX class, it's easy to render the buffer on a 3D shape instead of a 2D canvas node.

*Settings*

First, you need to install first VLC video player.

Then you need some dependencies: [vlcj-3.6.0.jar](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/releases/tag/vlcj-3.6.0), jna-3.5-2.jar & platform-3.5.2.jar and slfj4j-api.1.7.12.jar.

Also, I'll use some custom 3D shapes from the [FXyz](https://github.com/Birdasaur/FXyz) library, though you can use the regular ones from the API, like a `Box`.

*Basis*

The trick to render video on a 3D shape is using the diffuse map of its material, that takes an image, and defines its texture.

You can find some more information on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881887/using-texture-for-triangle-mesh-without-having-to-read-write-an-image-file) or [here](http://jperedadnr.blogspot.com/2015/01/creating-and-texturing-javafx-3d-shapes.html).

So for every frame available we will create a new image and set it as the diffuse map:

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = nativeBuffer.getByteBuffer(0, nativeBuffer.size());
BufferFormat bufferFormat = ((DefaultDirectMediaPlayer) mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer()).getBufferFormat();
WritableImage textureImage = new WritableImage(bufferFormat.getWidth(), bufferFormat.getHeight());
if (bufferFormat.getWidth() > 0 && bufferFormat.getHeight() > 0) {
    textureImage.getPixelWriter().setPixels(0, 0, bufferFormat.getWidth(), bufferFormat.getHeight(), pixelFormat, byteBuffer, bufferFormat.getPitches()[0]);
    // apply new frame as texture image to the 3D shape's material
    material.setDiffuseMap(textureImage);
}
```

An `AnimationTimer` will allow updating the frames and the texture.

*Sample*

This is a working sample that renders video on a segmented torus.

```
public class Video3D extends Application {

    static {
        // path to the VLC video player
        System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC");
    }

    // http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/
    // (c) copyright 2008, Blender Foundation / www.bigbuckbunny.org
    private static final String VIDEO_FILE = "C:\\BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4";

    private final DirectMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent;
    private final WritablePixelFormat<ByteBuffer> pixelFormat;

    private final SegmentedTorusMesh torus = new SegmentedTorusMesh(50,40,12,3.2d,4.5d);
    private final PhongMaterial material = new PhongMaterial(Color.WHEAT);

    private double mousePosX, mousePosY;
    private double mouseOldX, mouseOldY;
    private final Rotate rotateX = new Rotate(-20, Rotate.X_AXIS);
    private final Rotate rotateY = new Rotate(240, Rotate.Y_AXIS);

    private final AnimationTimer timer;

    public TestVLC(){
        mediaPlayerComponent = new TestMediaPlayerComponent();
        pixelFormat = PixelFormat.getByteBgraInstance();
        timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                renderFrame();
            }
        };
    }
    protected void startTimer() {
        mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(VIDEO_FILE);
        timer.start();
    }

    protected void stopTimer() {
        mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().stop();
        timer.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        torus.setCullFace(CullFace.NONE);
        torus.setzOffset(1.4);
        torus.setMaterial(material);

        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
        camera.getTransforms().addAll (rotateX, rotateY, new Translate(0, 0, -30));

        Group root3D = new Group(camera,torus);

        SubScene subScene = new SubScene(root3D, 800, 600, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
        subScene.setFill(Color.AQUAMARINE);
        subScene.setCamera(camera);

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(subScene);
        Button play = new Button("Play");
        play.setOnAction(e->startTimer());
        Button stop = new Button("Stop");
        stop.setOnAction(e->stopTimer());
        ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar(play, stop);
        toolBar.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        pane.setRight(toolBar);
        pane.setPrefSize(600,400);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

        scene.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent me) -> {
            mouseOldX = me.getSceneX();
            mouseOldY = me.getSceneY();
        });
        scene.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent me) -> {
            mousePosX = me.getSceneX();
            mousePosY = me.getSceneY();
            rotateX.setAngle(rotateX.getAngle()-(mousePosY - mouseOldY));
            rotateY.setAngle(rotateY.getAngle()+(mousePosX - mouseOldX));
            mouseOldX = mousePosX;
            mouseOldY = mousePosY;
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Video - JavaFX 3D");
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    @Override
    public final void stop() throws Exception {
        stopTimer();

        mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().stop();
        mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().release();
    }

    /**
     * Implementation of a direct rendering media player component that renders
     * the video to a JavaFX canvas.
     * https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-javafx/blob/master/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/javafx/test/JavaFXDirectRenderingTest.java
     */
    private class TestMediaPlayerComponent extends DirectMediaPlayerComponent {

        public TestMediaPlayerComponent() {
            super(new TestBufferFormatCallback());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Callback to get the buffer format to use for video playback.
     */
    private class TestBufferFormatCallback implements BufferFormatCallback {

        @Override
        public BufferFormat getBufferFormat(int sourceWidth, int sourceHeight) {
            final int width = sourceWidth;
            final int height = sourceHeight;
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                torus.setMajorRadius(width/100);
                torus.setMinorRadius(height/40);
            });
            return new RV32BufferFormat(width, height);
        }
    }

    protected final void renderFrame() {
        Memory[] nativeBuffers = mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().lock();
        if (nativeBuffers != null) {
            Memory nativeBuffer = nativeBuffers[0];
            if (nativeBuffer != null) {
                ByteBuffer byteBuffer = nativeBuffer.getByteBuffer(0, nativeBuffer.size());
                BufferFormat bufferFormat = ((DefaultDirectMediaPlayer) mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer()).getBufferFormat();
                WritableImage textureImage = new WritableImage(bufferFormat.getWidth(), bufferFormat.getHeight());
                if (bufferFormat.getWidth() > 0 && bufferFormat.getHeight() > 0) {
                    textureImage.getPixelWriter().setPixels(0, 0, bufferFormat.getWidth(), bufferFormat.getHeight(), pixelFormat, byteBuffer, bufferFormat.getPitches()[0]);
                    material.setDiffuseMap(textureImage);
                }
            }
        }
        mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().unlock();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

And these are just two snapshots of what you will get.

[image: Pic1]

[image: Pic2]

Answer (score 5):

In addition to jewelsea's and José's more elegant solutions you could always position a MediaView manually in 3d space e. g. as 6 faces of a cube:

```
public class VideoCubeDemo extends Application {

    Random rnd = new Random();

    // size of the cube
    double size = 320;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws MalformedURLException {

        // create media views
        List<String> videoFiles = new ArrayList<>();

        videoFiles.add( getClass().getResource("funny_cats_compilation_2012.mp4").toExternalForm());
        videoFiles.add( getClass().getResource("funny_cats_compilation_2012.mp4").toExternalForm());
        videoFiles.add( getClass().getResource("funny_cats_compilation_2012.mp4").toExternalForm());
        videoFiles.add( getClass().getResource("funny_cats_compilation_2012.mp4").toExternalForm());
        videoFiles.add( getClass().getResource("funny_cats_compilation_2012.mp4").toExternalForm());
        videoFiles.add( getClass().getResource("funny_cats_compilation_2012.mp4").toExternalForm());

        // create faces for the cube
        // original cube face code from http://www.javafxapps.in/tutorial/Creating-3D-Cube-in-javafx.html
        MediaView r;
        int videoIndex;

        Group cube = new Group();

        List<MediaView> cubeFaces = new ArrayList<>();

        // back face
        videoIndex = 0;
        r = createMediaView(videoFiles.get( videoIndex));
        r.setTranslateX(-0.5 * size);
        r.setTranslateY(-0.5 * size);
        r.setTranslateZ(0.5 * size);

        cubeFaces.add( r);

        // bottom face
        videoIndex = 1;
        r = createMediaView(videoFiles.get( videoIndex));
        r.setTranslateX(-0.5 * size);
        r.setTranslateY(0);
        r.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
        r.setRotate(90);

        cubeFaces.add( r);

        // right face
        videoIndex = 2;
        r = createMediaView(videoFiles.get( videoIndex));
        r.setTranslateX(-1 * size);
        r.setTranslateY(-0.5 * size);
        r.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
        r.setRotate(90);

        cubeFaces.add( r);

        // left face
        videoIndex = 3;
        r = createMediaView(videoFiles.get( videoIndex));
        r.setTranslateX(0);
        r.setTranslateY(-0.5 * size);
        r.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
        r.setRotate(90);

        cubeFaces.add( r);

        // top face
        videoIndex = 4;
        r = createMediaView(videoFiles.get( videoIndex));
        r.setTranslateX(-0.5 * size);
        r.setTranslateY(-1 * size);
        r.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
        r.setRotate(90);

        cubeFaces.add( r);

        // front face
        videoIndex = 5;
        r = createMediaView(videoFiles.get( videoIndex));
        r.setTranslateX(-0.5 * size);
        r.setTranslateY(-0.5 * size);
        r.setTranslateZ(-0.5 * size);

        cubeFaces.add( r);

        // create cube with all faces
        cube.getChildren().addAll( cubeFaces);

        // initial cube rotation
        cube.getTransforms().addAll(new Rotate(45, Rotate.X_AXIS), new Rotate(45, Rotate.Y_AXIS));

        // animate cube
        Point3D rotateAxis = new Point3D(1,1,1); // rotate around X, Y and Z
        Timeline animation = new Timeline();
        animation.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(cube.rotationAxisProperty(), rotateAxis), new KeyValue(cube.rotateProperty(), 0d)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), new KeyValue(cube.rotationAxisProperty(), rotateAxis), new KeyValue(cube.rotateProperty(), 360d))
                );
        animation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

        // add objects to scene
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(cube);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1600, 900, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
        scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        scene.setCamera(new PerspectiveCamera());

        primaryStage.setResizable(true);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        // play videos and animation
        for( MediaView mediaPlayer: cubeFaces) {
            mediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().play();
        }
        animation.play();

    }

    private MediaView createMediaView( String path) {

        Media media = new Media( path);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer( media);
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.8);
        mediaPlayer.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);

        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView( mediaPlayer);
        mediaView.setFitHeight(size);
        mediaView.setFitWidth(size);
        mediaView.setPreserveRatio( false);

        return mediaView;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]