# How to create a cube with all faces of different colors in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I created a box and applied a texture to it. Is it possible to apply (and how) a different texture to each face of the cube? I have read some solutions but have not fully understood them.

I'm using JavaFX 11.0.2 and openJDK 11

This is the code of the box:

```
private Box prepareBox() {
        PhongMaterial material = new PhongMaterial();
        material.setDiffuseMap(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/wood.jpg")));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the following presentation slides 25 to 30 (UV mapping on a cube).

https://www.slideshare.net/jpt1122/con2221-weaver-exploringjavafx3d

An alternate solution is to use this TextureAtlas implementation:
[Create a cube using different textures in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881905/create-a-cube-using-different-textures-in-javafx)

Comment: Alternatively you can either change the cube mesh or the texture coordinates, as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34007952/3956070) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26834319/3956070)