# applying texture to mesh in javafx

Tags: javafx, mesh, javafx-3d

I was having trouble applying a texture to a mesh using JavaFX and FXyz 0.1.1.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831871/coloring-individual-triangles-in-a-triangle-mesh-on-javafx) and even with the detailed answer there could not figure it out.  I started over from scratch, copying the code from the answer exactly and the scene is black with no visible icosohedron.

I'm using Java 8.  The provided image is a gif and the code references it as a png.  I've tried it with both png and gif versions of the file.  As far as I can tell everything else is exactly as the code in the answer to the referenced question.

I am able to run [this](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/7206287) and texture that sphere without issue, but I would like to be able to use an icosohedron instead of a sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the FXyz [library](https://bintray.com/jpereda/FXyz3D/fxyz3d/0.1.1) you can very easily apply different textures to an icosahedron or to any of the different primitives you can find in the [library](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz/tree/master/FXyz-Core/src/main/java/org/fxyz3d/shapes/primitives).

This snippet shows 5 different texture modes:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);   
    camera.setTranslateY(3);
    camera.setTranslateX(4);
    camera.setTranslateZ(-15);

    IcosahedronMesh icoLine = new IcosahedronMesh(100, 0);
    icoLine.setDrawMode(DrawMode.LINE);
    icoLine.getTransforms().addAll(new Rotate(10, Rotate.X_AXIS), new Rotate(-20, Rotate.Y_AXIS));

    IcosahedronMesh icoColor = new IcosahedronMesh(100, 0);
    icoColor.setTextureModeNone(Color.LIGHTGREEN);
    icoColor.getTransforms().addAll(new Rotate(20, Rotate.X_AXIS), new Rotate(-20, Rotate.Y_AXIS));

    IcosahedronMesh icoFunction = new IcosahedronMesh(100, 0);
    icoFunction.setTextureModeVertices3D(1530, p -> Math.cos(p.z));
    icoFunction.getTransforms().addAll(new Rotate(30, Rotate.X_AXIS), new Rotate(-20, Rotate.Y_AXIS));

    IcosahedronMesh icoFaces = new IcosahedronMesh(100, 0);
    icoFaces.setTextureModeFaces(5);
    icoFaces.getTransforms().addAll(new Rotate(20, Rotate.X_AXIS), new Rotate(-10, Rotate.Y_AXIS));

    IcosahedronMesh icoImage = new IcosahedronMesh(100, 0);
    icoImage.setTextureModeImage(getClass().getResource("icon.jpg").toExternalForm());
    icoImage.getTransforms().addAll(new Rotate(20, Rotate.X_AXIS), new Rotate(-20, Rotate.Y_AXIS));

    IcosahedronMesh icoPattern = new IcosahedronMesh(100, 0);
    icoPattern.setTextureModePattern(Patterns.CarbonPatterns.CARBON_KEVLAR, 100);
    icoPattern.getTransforms().addAll(new Rotate(20, Rotate.X_AXIS), new Rotate(-30, Rotate.Y_AXIS));


    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.add(new Group(icoLine), 0, 0);
    grid.add(new Group(icoColor), 1, 0);
    grid.add(new Group(icoFunction), 2, 0);

    grid.add(new Group(icoFaces), 0, 1);
    grid.add(new Group(icoImage), 1, 1);
    grid.add(new Group(icoPattern), 2, 1);
    Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 600, 400, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
    scene.setCamera(camera);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle(("Icosahedron - FXyz3D"));
    primaryStage.show(); 

}
```

[image: Icosahedra Textures]

Comment: Thank you for answer and the examples.  They've gotten me going in the direction I was looking for.